# subprocess.call input is int. how can we make it string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I've been trying to simply see if the "networking" service is found in the "ps -A" command. However, getting the error: "TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable". this is my code:

```
import subprocess
tmp = subprocess.call('ps -A', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
if 'networking' in tmp:
    print("networking service is up an running!")
else:
    print("networking service is not up :(")
```

Even when using the .decode() at the end of the `subprocess.call` function => it says that .decode() isn't supported here...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.call` returns the an integer with `0` meaning all is fine.

Try [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.check_output('ps -A', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
if b'networking' in p:
    print("networking service is up an running!")
else:
    print("networking service is not up :(")
```

Comment: *note:*  you may also specify the encoding kwarg, so you don't need the bytestring literal there.   +1

Comment: Yes. Tried this but got a decoding error with `utf-8` on MacOS X.

Comment: Was a typo. `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 34772: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: OK. Works with `latin1`.

Comment: In Python 3, `subprocess.call(..., universal_newlines=True)` handles encoding issues transparently.  You'll also want to look into switching to `subprocess.run()` with 3.5+

Comment: @tripleee Thanks but did nor work form with Python 3.6. Still the same error.

Comment: Sounds like your Python is misconfigured for your locale then ...?

Comment: >>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'UTF-8'
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('de_DE', 'UTF-8')
>>> locale.getlocale()
('de_DE', 'UTF-8')